# Jenkins - Execute shell commands with wildcards

Tags: java, shell, maven, jenkins

I am trying to get Jenkins to execute a shell command but still allow wildcards to be used. Here's what I'm trying to do for reference:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=snapshots -Durl=http://nexus.example.net/content/repositories/snapshots -DpomFile=Spigot/Spigot-Server/pom.xml -Dfile=Spigot/Spigot-Server/target/spigot-*.jar
```

I need to be able to deploy this jar through the above command because the git repository for that project isn't owned or operated by me, so I need to be able to deploy it directly to my own Nexus instance. In order to ensure that it will support all possible versions of the compiled jar, I must use a wild card. Unfortunately, when Jenkins tries to execute the command, it takes the wildcard literally. I'm really not sure how to solve this, I would appreciate any help you can provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a simple single .jar file try this:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=snapshots -Durl=http://nexus.example.net/content/repositories/snapshots -DpomFile=Spigot/Spigot-Server/pom.xml -Dfile=$(find Spigot/Spigot-Server/target/ -name 'spigot-*.jar')
```

If it's multiple files, it's a bit more complicated:

The **maven deploy-file** parameters **files**, **classifiers** and **types** are used when you want to deploy multiple artifacts under the **same** **(groupId, artifactId, version)** - for example a **.jar** and **-sources.jar**

Even for that use case, the syntax is somewhat counterintuitive - you must use **file=file1.jar** for the **first artifact**, and then **files=file1-sources.jar,file1-test-sources.zip,..** for the **rest**, while using  **classifier/classifiers** (and **packaging/types**) in the same way (positional) to specify classifier/type of each artifact you are uploading.

If your use case is **uploading artifacts of different versions**, you will need to do **one maven deploy-file call for each version**.

You also might consider some alternatives:

1. (depending on how many artifacts, and how often new ones will come) - **upload these artifacts manually** to Nexus
2. Make you Nexus **proxy another Nexus repository** that serves these artifacts.

Comment: Thank you very much! For the record, I was only trying to deploy a single file.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you just want the `*` to be passed on directly, just use single quotes to avoid the shell from applying globbing:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file [...] '-Dfile=Spigot/Spigot-Server/target/spigot-*.jar'
```

Comment: I actually wanted the opposite. It _doesn't_ glob which is the issue.

Comment: @mattrick: Ah. It would probably be worth clarifying that. You may need to do that in multiple commands... not sure.

Comment: @JonSkeet, FWIW, the post does state "it takes the wildcard literally" :-)  Interestingly, if the command were run in bash outside of Jenkins, the shell indeed attempts to glob before executing the command unless your quote suggestion is followed. Not sure why the Jenkins shell doesn't follow the same behavior.

Comment: @tony19: Well I was certainly confused by the description, so I suspect others may be too. Anyway, will delete my answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to deploy **multiple** files I think problem is **not** with Jenkins or bash command, but with usage of [Maven Deploy Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html).

Documentation states

> ```
> file  File    -   File to be deployed.
> User property is: file.
> ```

and
if you would deploy extra artifacts,  use

> ```
> files     String  -   A comma separated list of files for each of the
>                     extra side artifacts to deploy. If there is a 
>                     mis-match in the number of entries in types or
>                     classifiers, then an error will be raised. 
> User property is: files.
> ```

Thus it would be better if you specify **extra** files to deploy explicitly by using additional `files`,  `types`, `classifies` parameters, ex.:

```
... -Dfile=Spigot/Spigot-Server/target/main-spigot.jar \
-Dfiles=$(ls -1d Spigot/Spigot-Server/target/spigot-*.jar | paste -sd ,) -Dtypes=... -Dclassifiers=...
```